# boost::interprocess shared memory segment function find() hangs at startup if the segment is already there

Tags: c++, boost, ipc, shared-memory

I'm attempting to use boost's shared memory functionality to put a vector into shared memory, as discussed by [this boost article](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container).

It mostly all works, except sometimes, when I start up and the shared memory segment is already there, managed_shared_memory::find will hang.

The debugger shows it stuck on some interprocess mutex in the bowels of boost::interprocess.

**I've checked and I have no other process that would be running that hangs on to this shared memory.**

If follow my code, the test starts and if it discovers the segment already existing, it calls destroyMyShm().   destroyMyShm()  opens up the segment and tries to call managed_shared_memory::find() on the vector that should be inside that segment.  This find hangs.

Note if I just call shared_memory_object::remove() everything is ok.  I don't know if this will cause a leak though because the vector won't be properly destroyed.

Is there anything I can do about this?   Possibly a bug in boost?

Is it safe to just call shared_memory_object::remove() and forget about managed_shared_memory::destroy() ?

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>

typedef  boost::interprocess::allocator<std::string, boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;
typedef  boost::interprocess::vector<std::string, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;


static const char *kSharedMemorySegmentName("myseg");
static const char *kSharedMemoryVectorName("myvec");

bool isMyShmCreated();
void  destroyMyShm();
void initMyShm(size_t);

//pardon my google-test method here...
TEST(MyTest, SharedMemoryTest) {
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    if (isMyShmCreated())
    {
        destroyMyShm();  //hangs in here (see below)
    }
    EXPECT_FALSE(isMyShmCreated());
    initMyShm(1000000);
    EXPECT_TRUE(isMyShmCreated());


    managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, kSharedMemorySegmentName);
    MyVector *vec = segment.find<MyVector>(kSharedMemoryVectorName).first;

    EXPECT_TRUE(vec != 0);
    vec->push_back(std::string("item 1"));
    vec->push_back(std::string("item 2"));


   destroyMyShm();
}


void initMyShm(size_t size) {
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    if (isMyShmCreated()) {
        log("already created");
    }
    managed_shared_memory segment(open_or_create, kSharedMemorySegmentName, size);
    MyVector *vec = segment.find<MyVector>(kSharedMemoryVectorName).first;
    if (!vec)
    {
        const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
        segment.construct<MyVector>(kSharedMemoryVectorName)(alloc_inst);
    } else
    {
        vec->clear();
    }
}

bool isMyShmCreated()
{
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    try
    {
        managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, kSharedMemorySegmentName);
        return segment.check_sanity();
    } catch (const interprocess_exception &ex) {
        std::cout << "managed_shared_memory ex: "  << ex.what();
    }
    catch (const std::exception &ex) {
        std::cout << "managed_shared_memory ex: "  << ex.what();
    }
    catch (const std::string& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "managed_shared_memory ex: "  << ex;
    } catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "managed_shared_memory ex: ?";
    }
    return false;
}

void destroyMyShm() {
    using namespace boost::interprocess;
    try
    {
        managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, kSharedMemorySegmentName);
        // hangs on segment.find() below:
        if (segment.find<MyVector>(kSharedMemoryVectorName).first)  
            segment.destroy<MyVector>(kSharedMemoryVectorName);
    } catch (...) {}
    try
    {
        shared_memory_object::remove(kSharedMemorySegmentName);
    } catch (...) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't you be using `basic_string<char, ShmemAllocator>` instead of `string`? your vector is actually container of containers - all should use shared allocator I think. (you'd need two, one for the string - of chars - second for vector - of your special string)

**EDIT**: there is a link at the end of that boost page named 'Container of Containers'.... read it! (I was just guessing and that page proves I was correct.)

**LINKS:**
[Boost: Creating vectors in shared memory](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container)
[Boost: Containers of containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.containers_of_containers)